# How do you write XML Schema for this XML?

Tags: xml, xsd

How do you write XSD for this xml stanza?

```
<sales>
    <orders>
        <order type="online">1234</order>
        <order type="online">2334</order>
        <order type="retail">7834</order>
        <order type="retail">5654</order>
    </orders>
</sales>
```

Answer (score 1):

Search c:\program files for xsd.exe ([Xml Schema Definition Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)). Then use it as **xsd.exe c:\your.xml**. Here is output for your xml-scrap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="sales" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="sales" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="en-US">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="orders">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="order" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent msdata:ColumnName="order_Text" msdata:Ordinal="1">
                    <xs:extension base="xs:unsignedShort">
                      <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

... of course, it could be simplified if you understand the elements a bit.

```
<xs:element name="sales">
  <xs:complexType>      
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="orders">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="order" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                  <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>                        
                  </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a one off, you can get various tools to generate a generic schema from your XML, but none will know exactly which constraints are important. For instance, is it important to constraint "type" in your example to be only "online" or "retail"? To get it right, you'l need to write the XML Schema yourself.

Though XML Schema in the whole is complex, you can get the basics from reading the [XML Schema Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/) or one of the many tutorials out there.

Answer (score 1):

There's an infinite number of schemas for which your XML document is a valid instance. To write a schema we need to know more about the set of valid instances. For example, are "online" and "retail" the only valid values of the type attribute, or are there other valid values? What about the content (1234, etc) - is this always four digits, or is it purely coincidence that all the values you showed us are exactly four digits?

There are a number of tools that do a pretty good job at generating a schema from a single instance, but they have to make guesses about the answers to questions such as the above.